# Limiting CPU usage of Mariadb proccess doesn't work

Tags: linux, nginx, apache-2.4, centos7, mariadb

I'm building a server that runs Mariadb 10.5, apache, nginx and PHP-FPM.
The server have 16 cores and 32GB Ram.
This server suppose to work under load, but it doesn't because Mariadb is using 1500%, which causes the whole server to bottleneck.

This is my my.cnf

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G

innodb_log_file_size = 3G

innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M

max_allowed_packet=1024M

interactive_timeout=30

wait_timeout=120

max_connections = 1000

thread_pool_size=4

skip-name-resolve=1

table_definition_cache=500

performance_schema=ON

max_heap_table_size=1024M

tmp_table_size=1024M

table_open_cache=16000

join_buffer_size=512000
```

As you can see, i've tried to limit the CPU usage with thread_pool_size=4, but it doesn't change anything.

Hopefully some one can tell what I'm missing here

Comment: High CPU/load-average is caused by inadequate indexes and/or poor formulation of queries.  Find a slow query and let's fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You use thread_pool_size=4, but you also need to have thread_handling=pool-of-threads, to take effect. Please also note, that thread_pool_size is merely a hint- while it tries to have 4 CPUs in running state, it is allowed to create more for the long running queries. Also it does not take background innodb threads into account.

Comment: This suggestion may help with _connections_, but not with _CPU_.